# jQuery dialog box to remember user

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm using the jQuery Dialog box on my website, to display a form. I don't want the Dialog box to pop up more than once, for the same user. So once they have either filled out their details or clicked on X (close) I don't want them to see this message again.  I've read I can use cookies within the form, but unable to find any exact code I could use. Here's the code so far:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
        <div class="site-container">

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">


  <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="92" title="Test"]' ); ?>
</div>
```

What's the best solution for this?

Many thanks
Rachael

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)-Oject in the close-function:

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        if(localStorage.getItem("closed") !== 'yes'){
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                close: function(){
                     localStorage.setItem("closed", "yes");
                }
             });
         }
     });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-container">

     <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">


     <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="92" title="Test"]' ); ?>
</div>
```

You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26924958/4202224) answer, were I get more precise about the localStorage-Object and Cookies

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyqx9fp6/) (onLoad)**
**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/f23kt4fp/) (onClick)**

Comment: Thanks Empiric. I've added the above code, to inside the script tags. I've read your post on the other Q but it's new to me so I must be missing something - it's still popping up after I've entered details then refreshed the page.

Comment: please try a `console.log(localStorage.getItem("closed"))` to see if the object is set correctly in the close-function

Comment: @RachJenn i added a fiddle in my answer. Close the dialog there and just re-run the fiddle.

Comment: Not 100% sure where to add that. I've tried.... close: function(){
           localStorage.setItem("closed", "yes");
           console.log(localStorage.getItem("closed"))
        }

Comment: And... close: function(console.log(localStorage.getItem("closed"))){
           localStorage.setItem("closed", "yes");
        }

Comment: Both didn't stop the box reappearing?

Comment: @RachJenn `console.log()` just add output to to console in e.g. firebug, where you can check if the right value is set. Have you checked my fiddle ?

Comment: I just have, thanks for that. Here's the link, http://www.peakdistricttradefair.co.uk/test/ I"m getting NULL in the console.

Comment: @RachJenn, in your code, replace your dialog-function with the code I posted, this should work

Comment: Thanks for that, I've done it but it's still popping up. There was a JS issue with another file which I've removed.

Comment: @RachJenn i updated my answer on how your code should look like on your testpage

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.
When user interact with close button you can set the cookie and the next time you can load the cookie and conditionally open dialog.